# Mobile APK and TV APK under the same app name. Want to unpublish TV app

Tags: console, google-play, playback

I have an app on Play console, which contains APK for Mobile version and TV version. I want to unpublish only the TV version app without affecting the mobile version, but can not find a way to do it.

If I try to unpublish the app it removes both version.